# reduce down array to remove duplicate matchId entries from left to right

Tags: javascript, typescript, angularfire, reduce

I'm **pushing** an object to an array when the user updates a score for a matchId, I would like my final array to remove all the oldest duplicates of matchId, so from index 0 until the end, is there way?

I have this:

```
cleanData =
    0: {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1"}
    1: {matchId: "271692", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1"}
    2: {matchId: "271700", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1"}
    3: {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "6", awayTeamScore: "6"}
    4: {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8"}
    5: {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8"}
    6: {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "0"}
```

I would like this:

```
0: {matchId: "271692", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1"}
1: {matchId: "271700", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1"}
2: {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "0"}
```

My code:

```
saveResult(data: any, pushMatchId: any) {
    if (this.savedResults) {
      let cleanData = this.savedResults.map((item) => {
        return {
          matchId: item.matchId,
          homeTeamScore: item.homeTeamScore,
          awayTeamScore: item.homeTeamScore,
        };
      });
      data.map((item) => {
        cleanData.push(item);
      });
      this.db.collection("users").doc(this.user.uid).update({
        results: cleanData,
      });
    } else {
      this.db.collection("users").doc(this.user.uid).set({
        results: data,
      });
    }

  }
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add the code you are trying with now.

Comment: A better approach is using a map to store your match information and for user to update score

Comment: Is the array guaranteed to be ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the latest objects in the array are the ones you want, then you could use [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) and just add to the final result the matches that are not already in the final array, something like:

```js
let matches = [
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271692", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271700", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "6", awayTeamScore: "6" },
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8" },
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8" },
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "0" },
];

let result = matches.reduceRight(
  (p, c) => (!p.find((o) => o.matchId === c.matchId) ? [...p, c] : p),
  []
);

console.log(result);
```

or a more optimized approach, storing the latest matchIds in a map:

```js
let matches = [
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271692", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271700", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "6", awayTeamScore: "6" },
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8" },
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8" },
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "0" },
];

let matchIds = new Map();
let result = matches.reduceRight((p, c) => {
  if (!matchIds.get(c.matchId)) {
    matchIds.set(c.matchId, true);
    return [...p, c];
  }
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

In the case where you want to check beforehand if there are already matches with a certain id and filter them out before adding the latest one, you could do something like:

```js
let matches = [
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271692", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271700", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
];

let addMatch = (match) => {
  matches = matches.filter(({
    matchId
  }) => matchId !== match.matchId);
  return matches.push(match), matches;
};

let latest = { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "6", awayTeamScore: "6" };

addMatch(latest); // Add the latest match, replace if there was already a score

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Only concern I'd have with this answer is the nested looping, depending on the size of the array. Could be a performance issue.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid concern :) I thought that instead of `.find()` every time we could just store those matchIds that have already been added somewhere so that when we come across them then we know that they are already in the result. What do you think of option B that i just added?

Comment: Yeah, that's good! I used `Set` in my example but it's essentially the same idea of using a hash structure over an array

Comment: this worked but as @Chima has stated below, I would have preferred to have "Before you add to the array, do a check to see if the matchId is already in the array, if it is filter that out then add the new data. If not, add the new data". I've been trying all day to do that, it involves nesting for loops, two of them. In in the end, this solution works for me for now, thanks.

Comment: @artworkjpm I've edited my answer and added in the 3rd and last snippet a possible implementation of that. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the duplicates sounds like solving the problem after it's occurred. Why not prevent adding duplicates at all?

Before you add to the array, do a check to see if the matchId is already in the array, if it is filter that out then add the new data. If not, add the new data

Comment: I'd say that, if they were to reorganize things in general, there are better data structures for maintaining uniqueness (e.g., an object where the key is `matchId`). Searching an array every time isn't super efficient.

Comment: I like this answer, if matchId exists I'd slice it out then push the new index in? If you can show some code for this answer it would help me. What you're saying makes sense here

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a `Set` to keep track of `matchId` strings you have seen before, reverse the array, and filter it down based on whether the element has been seen. This solutions only works if the items are guaranteed to be ordered.

```js
const input = [
  {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1"},
  {matchId: "271692", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1"},
  {matchId: "271700", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1"},
  {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "6", awayTeamScore: "6"},
  {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8"},
  {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8"},
  {matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "0"}
];

const exists = new Set();

const unique = [...input].reverse().filter(({matchId}) => {
  if (!exists.has(matchId)) {
    exists.add(matchId);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
})

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: simply create a new array, backward for loop input array, then push unseen data to new array is more efficient. If you consider performance.

Comment: @Colin you'd still need the `Set` though right? Otherwise you're searching the new array each element

Comment: Yes, sir. seen and unseen data will still be handled by Set. I'm just saying reverse with filter here is not necessary.

Comment: @Colin Yeah, I guess that's fair. Technically it's still O(n) so I'm not sure how much it'd really matter

Comment: You could avoid the return true/false in your answer and simply do `.filter(({ matchId }) => !exists.has(matchId) && exists.add(matchId));` as that's already truthy/falsy.

Comment: Theoretically they are all O(n) with the same growth rate, but in practice if you consider performance for large array, why you waste time on reversing an array in place when you can simply for loop it from back? And you can reverse the array 11 times, it's still O(n), it doesn't matter, it's just not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve like this.

```js
data = [
  { matchId: "271692", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271700", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" },
  { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "0" },
];

function pushToData(data, newObject) {

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // debugger;
    if (data[i].matchId === newObject.matchId) {
      data.splice(i, 1);
      data.push(newObject);
      return;
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
pushToData(data, { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "999" });
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

if the idea is really to remove the old scores here is a solution:

```js
const input = 
      [ { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" } 
      , { matchId: "271692", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" } 
      , { matchId: "271700", homeTeamScore: "1", awayTeamScore: "1" } 
      , { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "6", awayTeamScore: "6" } 
      , { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8" } 
      , { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "8" } 
      , { matchId: "271691", homeTeamScore: "8", awayTeamScore: "0" } 
      ] 

let matchList = new Set()
for (let i=input.length;i--;)
  {
  if (matchList.has(input[i].matchId)) { input.splice(i, 1)  }
  else                                 { matchList.add(input[i].matchId) }
  }

console.log( input  )
```